# How to access dynamic key value in object key angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var value = attr.inlineEdit;
var field = value.substring(11);
```

//Here I have first_name in field variable

```
user.hit({field : scope.model}, auth.getCurrentUser().user_id).success(function () {
     console.log("Saved");
});
```

In the field key, I want that should be have first_name when I have first_name in field variable but I'm getting only field as a key.

It's weird but I need to do something on it.

Comment: i think {[field]: scope.model} is what you actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think {[field]: scope.model} is what you actually want.

Comment: This is awesome Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create nested object with `first_name` as a key:

```
{field : { first_name : scope.model }}
```